# C: Array elements disappearing

Tags: c, arrays

I am having some trouble figuring out why elements in "myWord" array are disappearing. "myWord" and "myLines" are both global variables from my .h file. The thing is, if I combine readWords() and printWords() functions, then it works. So what am I doing to cause this issue with "myWord"?

here is my output:

```
> Line: 0 (null) 
> Line: 1 (null) 
> Line: 2 ▒Á# 
> Line: 3 __libc_start_main
> Line: 4 (null) Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

snippet of .c file

```
void ReadWords(struct assem item)               //reads words into array    
{
    char *word;
    for(int s = 0; s < item.counter; s++)
            {
                item.word = strtok(item.myLines[s], " ");
                item.myWord[s] = item.word;
            }       
}

void printWords(struct assem item)
{
    for(int s = 0; s < item.counter; s++)
        {
            printf("Line: %i %s\n", s , item.myWord[s]);
        }
}
```

.h file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct assem
{
        char myString[101];                     //buffer
        char *myLines[20];                      //this will store the lines from a text file..up to 20 lines
        char *myWord[20];
        char *word;
        int counter;                            //counter for number of lines
                                                //printing stuff...prints file directly from whats STORED IN THE ARRAY

};

int readFile(FILE *FileToBeRead, struct assem *item);       //takes in the file that needs to be read and splits it into lines
void ReadWords(struct assem item);                          //stores the first word of each line in an array for evaluation
void printFile(struct assem item);                          //prints some stuff
int firstCheck(struct assem item);
void printWords(struct assem item);                                         //checks the first character if its instruction, label, or comment
```

Comment: You're storing pointers to `item.myLines[]` elements in `myWords[]`. Could you be deallocating those strings before you call `printWords()`?

Comment: Are you sure you allocated the `myLines` strings properly in the first place? You need to show more code to diagnose this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `ReadWords` is supposed to fill the structure with data. Its signature is:

```
void ReadWords(struct assem item);
```

Here, `item` is a local copy of the structure, because structures are passed by value. All changes to this local structure are lost after the function returns and the original struct will not be initialised. (Hence the garbage values you see when printing.)

You can fix this by passing a pointer to the struct:

```
void ReadWords(struct assem *item) 
{
    item->word = ...;
}
```

and the call it like this:

```
struct assem item;

ReadWords(&item);
```

Another possibility is to have the function return a structure:

```
struct assem ReadWords()
{
     struct assem item;

     item.word = ...;
     // ...
     return item;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
struct assem item = ReadWord();
```

Passing the structure by value to your print function is okay, though, because you don't modify the oiginal structure when printing. If the struct is big, you could also consider to pass it as a `const struct assem *` const pointer, however, to avoid copying. (Returning a struct has the same issue, so prefer pointers.)

Finally, I don't think that you need to use a struct member for tokenising. What should the meaning of `item.word` be after te line has been parsed?

Comment: and also you need to allocate some memory for the string returned by strok... (strdup) - and do not forget to free it later on

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon: Not if you keep all lines in memory with at least the same lifetime as the struct. It looks as if the lines were already stored in `item.mylines[i]`, but without the complete code one can't be sure. There seem to be some issues with the design of the struct.

Comment: M. Oehm is correct. items.myLines was implemented previously in the code